# How to show guidelines in Spyder?

Tags: spyder

In some IDEs like VSCode, Pycharm,... there is a guideline that shows the begin and end of a loop or function (as shown in the picture by arrow).

How to show this guidelines in Spyder IDE (or Anaconda)?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Those guides are only available in Spyder 4. To activate them, you need to go to the menu entry `Source > Show indent guides`.

Comment: My spyder version is: 3.3.6 (I installed it with Anaconda). I don't want to update my python, modules and Anaconda. Can I update my spyder to version 4? (Only spyder and not python and anything else.) If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: If this is the only feature you want to use in Spyder, it's better for you to stay with Spyder 3 and wait for a couple of months until Spyder 4 is more stable.